# JSON parser to get Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone

How can I get an image from the server using JSON parser?

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response 
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *results = [jsonString JSONValue]; 
NSArray *photos = [results objectForKey:@"ImageData"]; 

for (NSDictionary *ImageData in photos) 
{
    NSString *name = [ImageData objectForKey:@"name"]; 
    label.text = name; 
    //NSData *data = [ImageData objectForKey:@"src"];
    //UIImage *imgs = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]; 
    //img.image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:[ImageData objectForKey:@"src"]];
}
```

The commented code lines above are not showing the image.  So how can I display the image? I'm also using json framework from Google code.

Comment: Why would you want to use a JSON parser? JSON isn't particularly good for binary data.

Comment: i m getting all data from server except image Using Json parser.How to  convert imagedata as a Image while retriving.

Comment: Could you post the JSON code you need to extract the image from?

Comment: Does the 'src' field of each json object actually contain binary image data? You're treating it like that's the case, but that would be a very unusual use of json.

Comment: Can you show me the content in [ImageData objectForKey:@"src"] Dictionary for key value "src",so that your question would explain more...

Answer (score 0):

I use json-framework from Google Code. The URL is: [json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/).

Answer (score 0):

if you can modify the server response, ask for Base64 representation of the image. There are some pretty fast encoding/decoding routines available around - more at [CocoaDev: BaseSixtyFour](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour). However, depending on use case, it may still be bit of overkill.
Other option would be for example to get image url in JSON and then download it and then possibly store/cache it.

Answer (score 0):

Just try using this,since it seems you have missed up to alloc memory for UIImageView:

**img = [[UIImageView alloc]init];**

so even though the image is formed with NSData but not able to show on ImageView.

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response 
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *results = [jsonString JSONValue]; 
NSArray *photos = [results objectForKey:@"ImageData"]; 

for (NSDictionary *ImageData in photos) 
{
    NSString *name = [ImageData objectForKey:@"name"]; 
    img = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    img.image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:[ImageData objectForKey:@"src"]];   
}
```

Hope that will work :)